# How to create a file example_user.rb in your application root directory in ROR using Sublime Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently following Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial and not quite sure where to create the new example_user.rb file ([referenceed in section 4.4.5](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/rails_flavored_ruby#code-example_user)) because I am not sure what is meant by the root directory.

I understand how to create a new file using Sublime Text but I am not sure what path to place it in.  My educated guess would be to place it in: project_app/config/locales since it is an .rb file.

Any suggestions under what path I should place this code?
Also, how could you accomplish this task using the command line?

Many thanks!

Comment: Place it in app/models/ directory

Comment: Please use `Rails.root` to get your root path. Then place, example_user.rb there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial says to create a `example_user.rb` file in your application root directory which would just be `project_app/example_user.rb` (based on your educated guess).

`project_app/config/locales/` wouldn't be appropriate; that folder is used for something else entirely: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Zahid's comment about putting it in `app/models/` is sort of correct but doesn't actually follow the tutorial.  As you get further into the tutorial, you'll learn that this `example_user.rb` file will later be moved from `project_app/example_user.rb` to `project_app/app/models/user.rb` after you have a better understanding of what Rails' models are.

Good luck!